# Change color of button with mat-icon with a click

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-material

So I need to change the color of a button with a material icon when I click on it. I tried something like this:

HTML:

```
  <button (click)="activeSkill($event)" color="primary" mat-mini-fab>
    <mat-icon aria-label="" name='skill1'>euro_symbol</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

TS:

```
activeSkill(event){
    event.target.setAttribute('color', 'accent');
}
```

But this doesn't work. Which is the easier way to do this? And actually, if possible, how would I not use the default primary and accent colors, but a set of colors.

Comment: I didn't wrote properly my doubt and you're right, for the question above that's a pretty good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do the following. Add a reference `#button` to the button tag.

```html
<button (click)="activeSkill()" color="primary" mat-mini-fab #button>
  <mat-icon aria-label="" name='skill1'>add</mat-icon>
</button>
```

In your component use the ViewChild decorator

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('button') button: ElementRef;

  activeSkill() {
    (<any>this.button).color = 'accent';
  }
}
```

See this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppcntk).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the variable and using that can assing the color value button

below is a example

in html,

```
<button (click)="selectedColor = 'accent'" [color]="selectedColor" mat-mini-fab>
    <mat-icon aria-label="" name='skill1'>euro_symbol</mat-icon>
 </button>
```

in .ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'button-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['button-overview-example.css'],
})
export class ButtonOverviewExample {

  selectedColor: string = 'primary';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass local variable as ref. and set style accordingly like this -

```
activeSkill(event, ele) {
    console.log(event, ele);
    ele['_elementRef']['nativeElement']['className'] = 'mat-raised-button mat-accent';
  }

<button #btn (click)="activeSkill($event, btn)" md-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-buttons-suwezt?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: This didn't work properly when having a Mat Icon inside, the Mat Icon which was a circular button, turned into a flat button and lost it's properties. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, there are some best answer's are there above apart from this. Just posted if there is no way around try this !